# Servidor Apache PHP com processos demorados

Tags: php, apache

tenho uma aplicação que tem algumas requisições demoradas, gostaria de saber se o PHP como setar o php para funcionar com a melhor configuração possivel, gostaria de saber se enquanto ele faz essa requisição demorada eu conseguiria fazer uma nova requisição ou ele fica travado?

Comment: Deve ter algo a ver com a lógica do seu código. Mostre-nos o script que faz essa "requisição demorada", por favor.

Comment: O script é para ser demorado mesmo

Comment: Você pode rodar um profile (como o xdebug) e verificar onde é gargalo, depois pode [edit] a pergunta com o código fonte.

Comment: Se é coisa demorada, provavelmente deve ser executada localmente, direto pela linha de comando, sem passar pelo Apache, ou com uma tarefa agentada, ou com um loop infinito e um sleep entre os ciclos. Mas sem mais detalhes na pergunta, tudo é chute.

Comment: Lembre-se que pode [edit] a pergunta acrescentando mais detalhes, a ponto da pergunta ficar mais específica. Só cuidado para não descaracterizar a dúvida inicial a ponto de invalidar completamente as respostas existentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### O servidor Web (Apache) não fica travado enquanto executa uma requisição.

O Apache tem uma configuração padrão que pode atender várias requisições simultâneas. Ele pode fazer isso iniciando threads dentro de cada processo e iniciando novos processos.

O PHP, que é executado pelo Apache, [tem muitas configurações](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php) e talvez você deva explorar cada uma para entender quais podem te ajudar no seu caso. A "melhor" configuração é difícil de saber porque cada projeto tem uma necessidade diferente.

Porém, como qualquer programa que roda no servidor, dependendo do que ele estiver fazendo poderá "travar" aquele processo e uma nova requisição será atendida por outro processo. No Apache, como podem existir vários processos rodando, um processo demorado não vai evitar que outro execute, mas como a máquina é uma só, dependendo do tipo de operação que estiver fazendo, ela não será capaz de responder as requisições no tempo hábil. Por exemplo, se você tem o Apache e o MySQL instalado na mesma máquina e seu PHP executa uma consulta complexa ou faz operações em disco demoradas, a máquina toda ficará carregada demais para que o Apache ou qualquer outro processo possa rodar adequadamente.

O ideal é que você desenhe a sua aplicação para não rodar processos demorados dentro do servidor Web. Em casos em que processos demorados existem e não podem ser contornados, o seu script PHP deveria passar para outra aplicação dentro do servidor essa tarefa longa e o servidor Web ficaria liberado. Dessa forma, no lado do cliente, você teria alguma página onde poderia monitorar o andamento desse processo longo, liberando o servidor Web para fazer o serviço dele, que é atender às requisições de outros clientes. A outra forma é melhorar a configuração da máquina do servidor ou tentar otimizar o seu script/consultas SQL que ele executa para retornar mais rapidamente às requisições.

No final não há uma resposta de melhor configuração possível. Tudo depende de você entender as configurações e ajustar para o seu caso. É interessante investigar também o motivo do processo demorado.

Answer (score 1):

Não há essa restrição, mas depende do seu `SO` e do `hardware`. Como a sua configuração usa o `PHP` como um módulo do `Apache`, é o `Apache` que está gerenciando essas conexões, e ele já faz o gerenciamento das múltiplas requisições.

O conceito de `multitarefa` não é relacionado com o `PHP`, mas com o sistema operacional e com o `hardware`. A multitarefa, por exemplo, necessita de processador com núcleo múltiplo e `SO` que possa usar esses núcleos para várias execuções simultâneas.

O `PHP` roda até o limite de memória configurado. Se o seu script em execução ocupar toda a memória reservada aí o sistema cria uma "fila de execução". Coisas como a capacidade do link de conexão também podem influir no resultado. Esses problemas (latência, perda de pacotes, etc) normalmente são resolvidos com a operadora, e podem ter relação com o limite de banda contratado.

No `PHP`, as configurações gerais são feitas em `php.ini`, e a alteração do limite de memória é feita na diretiva `memory_limit`. Coisas como o tempo de resposta (`max_execution_time`) e o limite de tamanho p/ upload (`upload_max_filesize`), (`max_input_time`) também influenciam na execução dos scripts.

Comment: Entendi, mas qual a configuração eu mudo para deixar o php utilizar mais memoria e link?

Comment: Entao pelo que entendi, enquanto o script grande roda as outras paginas deveriam abrir normalmente é isso?